# How to select a ListBoxItem which is already selected OR to highlight previous selected ListBoxItem after setting SelectedIndex to -1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, selectedindex

I'm programming a simple listbox in windows phone 7. The listbox has some items and when I click any of items the app navigates to a new page.

From beginning to here, everything is good.

But I want end-user can select the item again which causes navigate to the next page again. But listbox as it is, doesn't allow me to select an already selected item again.

I tried to do this for allowing to select an item again.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(ListBox.SelectedIndex != -1 )
    {
       NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
       ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1; 
    }
}
```

I have alreadhy edited the `ListBoxItemTemplate` to highlight selected item, but when I use above code, I cannot highlight the selected item, because it changes SelectedIndex too fast.

So how can I allow user to select a selected item or how can I highlight previous selected item. Any suggestions or tips?

EDIT:
When using a normal ListBox , I can simply use :

```
listboxitem1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Blue);`
```

But when I edit template of listbox item this does throw exception, so I cannot still do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can edit the template of ListBoxItem and add a grid, fully front of listbox item. And bind the visibility property of this grid.

After this, you can change of the visibility according to selected index. This approach should work well if you're using a navigation with listbox.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

Look into implementing one of the other Event handlers for Mouse events on the ListBox. Such as the [Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can detect when the user clicks the ListBox without changing the selected index by keeping track of the previous selected index value.

Comment: What if user moves from one control to another using **Tab** button? In this case the even would not get fired

Comment: @RobertJ. I forgot to specify that it was in windows phone in the question body, sorry about that.

Comment: Mikanikal, I wish there was a click event. it seems windows phone doesn't have click event for listbox

Comment: @Robert J - In the Tab case, I would not expect that to make a "Selection" until the user hit Enter would just be another Event that would have to be handled. Unfortunately there is no single event for all user input.

Comment: @Jackjop. I will take a look at the windows phone implementation and respond if I find something.

Comment: Jackjop. If you are using the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls ListView then there are similar events to use that act the same way as the typical WinForms Mouse events. Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx for events available. I would suggest looking into 'Tapped' and the 'PointerReleased' events.